# cwd of subFolder in imported Module

Tags: python-3.x

It could be a simple question but i can't answer. It happens when i tried to change the folder of a config-file...
here is my programm-structure:

```
/{PROJECT_DIR_NAME}/main.py
                   /folder1/function_A.py
                   /folder1/json/configfile.json
                   /folder1/__init__.py
```

in the funtion_A.py:

```
def something:
    os.getcwd()
    with open("json/configfile.json") as f:
    ...
```

in the main.py:

```
import folder1.function_A
os.getcwd()
def xx():
    fuction_A.something()
    ...
```

if i run funtion_A directly, json file will be found, because the os.getcwd() returns "/{PROJECT_DIR_NAME}/folder1/".

But if i run main.py, the os.getcwd() returns "/{PROJECT_DIR_NAME}/", which will be passed to the function_A. It results: "not such file or dir: '/{PROJECT_DIR_NAME}/json/configfile.json'"

I have expected that "**init**.py" in the Module can retrieve the path automatically. But it doesn't...
I know i can surround this with chdir() or some ugly method.
I would like to ask if there is an elegant way to solve this problem? Or i do somthing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `json` file is relative to your module, you should use module directory to refer to it:

```
with open("json/configfile.json") as f:
```

becomes:

```
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"json/configfile.json")) as f:
```

so your module works whatever the current directory is.

Now if you cannot change the code of `function_A`, you can change the directory in the caller, perform the import and change back the directory. It's not very "pythonic" but in your case that would be efficient:

```
import folder1
# now we know where folder1 is located
oldp = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(folder1.__file__)  # it's a folder all right
import folder1.function_A   # "json/configfile.json" is valid now
# restore previous path
os.chdir(oldp)
```

Comment: yes, i've also tried this. But the imported Module come from some other people, there are hundred "with open()". It is not possible to change them all.